# Django how to update more than a row field at once

Tags: python, database, django

The code below would be fine for updating a row field:

```
t = TheForm.objects.get(id=1)
t.value = 1
t.save()
```

But what if I need to update 5-6 fields at once? Is there any direct way?

Like update `(value=1,value2=2)`

**EDIT**

I already know that I can do:

```
t.value1 = 1
t.value2 = 1
t.value3 = 1
```

But I am looking for a single line command like the Insert one for instance. (`TheForm(value1=1,value2=2,value3=3)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure!

```
t.value1 = 1
t.value2 = 2
t.save()
```

Alternatively,

```
TheForm.objects.filter(id=1).update(value=1, value2=2)
```

(And you could use `**kwargs` here)

Answer (score 0):

You can change as many fields as you want before you save.

```
t = TheForm.objects.get(id=1)
t.value1 = 1
t.value2 = 2
t.save()
```

You can also use the `update` method:

```
t = TheForm.objects.filter(id=1).update(value1=1,value2=2)
```

Note that using `update` is subtlety different. There wont be an error if the object with `id=1` does not exist. Pre- and post-save signals won't be sent when using `update`.